# Using one image view over other imageview having same width and height in the same layout

Tags: android

i am creating image editor app. i want to use one imageview over another imageview, one image view load image from gallery and the other imageview show a frame from drawable folder. Now the problem is that i can load image from gallery and showing it on image view but the when i click the apply button to apply frame on the loaded picture it gets crash... any solution please???

**My Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lay"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_filter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />


</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_laod"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="Load" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_filter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:text="Apply"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/b_filter"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Save" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_share"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/b_filter"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:text="Share"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp" />
```

My LogCat

```html
10-02 13:18:07.496 7126-7132/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
10-02 13:18:24.577 7126-7126/com.example.muhammadmehran.framedemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.muhammadmehran.framedemo, PID: 7126
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060056
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:804)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
        at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:17217)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setBackgroundResource(AppCompatImageView.java:123)
        at com.example.muhammadmehran.framedemo.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:102)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5205)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21162)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5452)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:762)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
```

Comment: `it gets crash..` Would you paste the logcat too?

Comment: what's there on `MainActivity.java:102`?

Comment: its a click listener on ApplyButton...  i write this code inside clickListener imageFilter.setImageResource(R.drawable.f3);